# Identify environment variable inside HTML

Tags: html, node.js, environment-variables

I'm setting the environment variable on startup like:

`"production": "NODE_ENV=production parcel build /src/index.html",`

I need to load a script  inside the `index.html`, the script is going to be ScriptA if `environment=production` and ScriptB if something else.
So I need to read/identify the environment inside my html file to make something like:

```
<script>
if (environment == prd) { 
   // Load Script A} 
   <script src="scriptA.js"/>
else {
   // Load script B
   <script src="scriptB.js"/>
}
</script>
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?
Also thought maybe just load a single script and inside this script I check the environment, but couldn't achieve this reading from `process.env`.

Comment: [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process) - Node.js intance, avaible on *back-end* only. HTML files, JS scripts etc. are represent *front-end* of your app. So you may access to `process.env` only during your server processing html, before it sent to client. *Template engines* might be useful for this case (like [Jade](https://jade-lang.com/) or [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)).

Comment: @Xeelley Thanks for your reply. Would you know if using `import-map-overrides` package could do the trick here?